# Ocultar encabezado de tabla con Javascript dentro de página Php

Tags: javascript, php

cordial saludo equipo quiero pedirles el siguiente favor con lo siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente código de una página con nombre Genero.php, este código lo llamare código general:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);   /*Stack overflow en Español, dicen que es mejor depurar y que esto es una mala practica pero que toca si se esta de afan*/
  require_once("connect/conexion.php"); 
  $sql2="Select Distinct Genero From discos ORDER BY Genero ASC"; /*Consulta para cargar el combobox*/
  $res2=$con->prepare($sql2);        /* es $con, no $con2  ya que $con es como esta definida en el archivo conexion.php */
  $res2->execute();
  $result2 = $res2->get_result();
  $rows2 = $result2->num_rows;
?>
<!Doctype html>  
<html>
  <center> 
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Listado de discos organizados por géneros musicales </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Genero.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <style type="text/css">
      table{
          border:1px solid;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          padding: 10px;
          }
         th, td, tr{
            border: 1px solid; 
         }
     </style> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('encabezado2').style.display ='none';
       </script>  

     <script language="JavaScript">
          function cerrar() {
           ventana=window.self;
           ventana.opener=window.self;
           ventana.close(); }
     </script>
     </head>   
           <div align="right">  
    
       <a href="http://clasicotk.epizy.com" target="_self">Volver al menú principal</a>
         </div>
         <div align="Center"> 
           <b><h3>BÚSQUEDA POR GÉNERO MUSICAL</h3></b>
         </div>
            <p> </p>
        <body bgcolor="D5DBDB">  <!--D5DBDB es el color gris -->
         Seleccione Género:
         <select id="Genero" onchange="seleccioneGenero()"> 
           
          <?php 
              while ($rows2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$rows2['Genero'],$rows2['Genero']); 
              } 
            ?>
         </select>
         <br></br>
         <table>
             <tr  id="encabezado2" bgcolor="#85C1E9">
               <th style="width: 8%">Iddisco</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Artista</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Trabajo</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Género</th>
               <th style="width: 10%">Año</th>
               <th style="width: 20%">Enlace</th>
             </tr>
           
             <tbody id="ans"> 
             </tbody>
         </table>
        </body> 
   </center>     
</html>
```

En este código general, podemos ver que la siguiente fracción de código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('encabezado2').style.display ='none';
       </script>
```

permite ocultar los elementos que están identificados con el ID= encabezado2
Para este caso el id que está identificados con el ID= encabezado2 es el encabezado de la tabla, que dentro del código general, es la siguiente fracción de código:

```
<tr  id="encabezado2" bgcolor="#85C1E9">
       <th style="width: 8%">Iddisco</th>
       <th style="width: 10%">Artista</th>
       <th style="width: 10%">Trabajo</th>
       <th style="width: 10%">Género</th>
       <th style="width: 10%">Año</th>
       <th style="width: 20%">Enlace</th>
     </tr>
```

Al ejecutar la página no me oculta dichos encabezados, agradezco que por favor me indiquen por qué razón no se ocultan, pues necesito que se oculten.

Saludos

Comment: El navegador lee la página de arriba hacia abajo y va ejecutando los scripts a medida que los va leyendo. Cuando tu ocultas el encabezado, ese encabezado aún no existe. La solución: Mover el script hacia abajo o poner un evento para detectar que la página se haya terminado de cargar y ahí recién ocultar el encabezado

Comment: Hola, no se ocultan por una razón y es que el navegador lee y ejecuta el código de arriba hacía abajo, y en tu código veo tienes dicho script en el head, por lo que JavaScript al ejecutarse no encontrará el elemento head. Al respecto puedes hacer una de dos cosas.
1. Colocar el script justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta body 
2. ejecutar el script dentro de window.onload = ()=> {
    //Tu código aquí.
}
Con la segunda forma, JavaScript esperará a que cargue todo para ejecutar tu código, pero a mi parecer colocar todos los scripts antes de cerrar body es la forma más legible y adecuada.

Comment: Es como te ha explicado @Yussef en su comentario. Conviene que que tengas todo el código JS en un solo bloque `script` (veo que tienes dos) y que encierres dentro de `DOMContentLoaded` todo el código que dependa de la carga del DOM, así, no se ejecutará el código hasta que el DOM esté cargado. Para más detalles [puedes consultar la doc en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).